# Column Name with "?" - How to map in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ms-access

I have a legacy MSaccess database with one of columns named: "Active?".
I'm using NHibernate and I tried mapping it this way:

```
Property<bool?>(x => x.Active, map => map.Column("Active?"));
```

Also, I've tried using backticks:

```
Property<bool?>(x => x.Active, map => map.Column("`Active?`"));
```

But I can't successfully map the above column name -

I always get this error:

```
{"Nullable object must have a value."}

Stack Trace:   
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
  at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
  at NHibernate.Driver.DriverBase.ExpandQueryParameters(IDbCommand cmd, 
      SqlString sqlString)
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExpandQueryParameters(IDbCommand cmd, 
      SqlString sqlString)
  at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.PrepareQueryCommand(QueryParameters queryParameters,
      Boolean scroll, ISessionImplementor session)
  at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters
      queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
  at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(
      ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean 
      returnProxies)
  at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters
      queryParameters)
```

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried square brackets?  map.Column("[Active?]")

Comment: Have you tried `...Column("[Active?]")` ?

Comment: I've just tried Column("[Active?]"), no luck.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using? there's a bug about this in 3.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you can't modify the original database's table structure (which would be ideal, but might break other code)

I can see one way around this, with a slight variation depending on how locked down the original is.

Create an MS Access Query in the DB, based upon the original table, and alias "Active?" to something sane.

```
select foo, bar, [Active?] as Active
from insane_table
```

You should be able to treat an MS Access Query object like a table, so long as it isn't to complex.

If you truly can't touch the original DB at all, I'd then create a second MS Access DB, and link to the table in the original DB (File -> External Data -> Link Tables in older version) - create a query in the new DB that does just that same aliasing trick.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried this yet, but I think this can't do insert/delete/update.

Comment: Oddly enough, quite often you can do those things through an MS Access query.